# Query ContentVersion with Community User

Tags: contentversion

I have a simple question.  Can users with Customer Community Login query the ContentVersion object?

Comment: what do you mean by query - running soql or accessing the record ? can you add more details to your question

Comment: I'm using the Customer Community Login License to upload a feeditem contentpost.  It should create a contentdocument.  I want to get the id of the ContentDocument by querying SOQL via ContentVersion object.  The id link should be RelatedRecordId field of FeedItem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the users with Customer Community can query ContentVersion records

```
String communityId=Network.getNetworkId();//Use community Id to figure logged in Users Current Community
```

> SELECT Id, 
>   FileType,
>   SystemModstamp,Title, ContentUrl,ContentDocumentId,ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId, PathOnClient, VersionData from contentVersion WHERE OwnerId =: UserInfo.getUserId() and NetworkId=: communityId order By CreatedDate DESC

Comment: Does the networkId always have to resemble the id of the community? Can i be inside a community and have my networkId == null?

Comment: No, your networkId will always have a value in Community Context.

Answer (score 0):

You can query ContentDocumentLink by LinkedEntityId and use ContentDocumentId field value. And use following URL to show for ex. file:

```
/sfsites/c/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/{$ContentDocumentId}
```